# How to set value to mat-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material, html-select, angular-material-6

How to set the value to mat-select?

```
    <mat-select formControlName="project" >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let project of projectList" [value]="project.projectid" 
        (click)="projectSelected(project.projectid)">
        {{project.project_name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I am trying to do it with this code, but it does not work.

```
this.form.patchValue({
  'project.projectid': 1
});
```

Comment: you have tried formControl.setValue()?

Comment: Try `this.form.patchValue({'project': 1});` since control name is `project`.

Comment: try this . [value]="project.projectid.toString()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a fork at stackblitz, here is the link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wiccq5

I think your problem is with the `[value]` because it seems to expect a string and you are passing a number.